# getting api data but chart not rendering

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, vue-chartjs

I am using Vue.js with Vue-chart.js and I am getting the array of data that should go in the chart from fetch, but the chart is not rendering with the code below

```
export default {
      extends: Line,
      data: () => ({
        chartdata: null,
        chartLabels: null,
        loaded: false
      }),
      mounted() {
        this.loaded = false
        const { id } = this.$route.params
          reportService.getReport(id)
          .then(data => {
            this.report = data.report
            const { usage, chartLabels } = data.report.license
            this.chartdata = usage
            this.chartLabels = chartLabels
            console.log(usage[0], chartLabels[0])
          }
          )
          this.loaded = true
          this.renderChart({
            labels: this.chartLabels,
            datasets: [
              {
                label: 'License Usage',
                data: this.chartData,
              },
            ],
            }, { responsive: true, maintainAspectRatio: false })
```

[image]

thanks for any help

Comment: did you try without using async/await?, in preference use created hook instead of mounte

Comment: After fetch you use `this.chartData = usage` but I can't see where `chartData` is used, only `usage` used at `:chart-data="usage"`. It seems you use wrong variable?

Comment: yes i took out async await and used mounted and changed the destructuring to const { usage, chartLabels } = data.report.license. With that console.log(usage[0], chartLabels[0]) returns the data